# How do I apply the string split method on a pandas dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, data-cleaning

I would like to replace some values in my dataframe that were entered in the wrong format. For example, 850/07-498745 should be 07-498745. Now, I used string split successfully to do so. However, it turns all previously correctly formatted strings into NaNs. I tried to base it on a condition, but still I have the same problem. How can I fix it ?

Example Input:

```
mylist = ['850/07-498745', '850/07-148465', '07-499015']
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: "mycolumn" }, inplace = True)
```

My Attempt:

```
df['mycolumn'] = df[df.mycolumn.str.contains('/') == True].mycolumn.str.split('/', 1).str[1]
df
```

Output:

[image]

What I wanted:

[image]

Comment: Following your logic, it would be: `df.loc[df.mycolumn.str.contains('/'), 'mycolumn'] = df.mycolumn.str.split('/').str[1]`. But in this case `anky_91` answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would also work, and may help you understand why your original attempt did not:

```
mask = df.mycolumn.str.contains('/')
df.mycolumn.loc[mask] = df.mycolumn[mask].str.split('/', 1).str[1]
```

You were doing `df['mycolumn'] = ...`, which I believe is just replacing the entire Series  for that column with the new one you formed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `split` with `/` and grab the last returning string from the list:

```
df['mycolumn'].str.split('/').str[-1]

0    07-498745
1    07-148465
2    07-499015
Name: mycolumn, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

For a regex solution:

```
df.mycolumn.str.extract('(?:.*/)?(.*)$')[0]
```

Output:

```
0    07-498745
1    07-148465
2    07-499015
Name: 0, dtype: object
```